# How to embed map into our android application?

Tags: android, google-maps

I was tried to embed google map into my android application. When I executed the application it display as below[image] 
could anyone help with this?. and my source code .

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my Manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

 to your xml file

Comment: can you post manifest?!

Comment: @Coderji i have posted

Answer (score 0):

You have just tried to develop with deprecated Google Maps Android API v1. This will not work for any new project since March.

Delete all the maps related code (seriously, this is the easiest path) and follow this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start to use new Google Maps Android API v2.

Comment: @MacieGorski i tried using API V2 but it shows the following error

Comment: Error:                                                     2013-11-18 11:12:41 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2013-11-18 11:12:41 - map2] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;